# How to do HTML comments in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

In NetBeans, for javascript and php files/code, you can easily comment lines of code by just selecting them and then clicking on the comment button as shown in this picture.

[image]

Is possible to perform the same action for HTML code? If yes, how?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To comment out html code (and javascript/php code), select the section of code you want to comment out and use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for Mac) keyboard shortcut. For html code this adds the `<!-- -->` tags around your code.

To uncomment, select the commented code and use the same keyboard shortcut. This will remove the comment tags.

Comment: On OSX you need to use `Cmd + Shift + C` instead of `Ctrl + Shift + C`.

Comment: In my case I am coding under the Symfony PHP framework, so unfortunately `{# ... #}` results in TWIG files, not the desired `<!-- ... -->`