# Comment and Uncomment JSP Netbeans 8

Tags: jsp

How can I comment and un-comment my `JSP` tags in `Netbeans 8`?
Is there any plug in?
the plug in that I found is deprecated `HTML/JSP/XML` Un/Comment

I know I should use `<%-- comment or code --%>` for commenting in JSP but for some reasons Netbeans 8 gives me an error.

if it is necessary, I can post the code too.

Comment: It would be more useful if we can see the code and the error message.

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out with this?

Comment: no I didn't do u have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just typed it wrong but the correct syntax is

```
<%-- comment or code --%>
```

Comment: i saw my code now and I did it right there but wrong here my bad ;)

Comment: I don't know of one for Netbeans 8.  This is what i use for 7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330739/how-to-do-html-comments-in-netbeans  I had a plugin for 6.  I switched to Intellij recently, so I haven't played with 8.  I would take a look at the key map and see if there is anything related in there.  Sorry I'm not more help.

Comment: no when I write JSP I do not have such a luxury. 
Is Intellij good IDE? everybody keeps talking about it
do you recommend to switch to that?

Comment: Yeah, I love IntelliJ.  Its a little pricing being that everythign else is free however jboss and tomcat are awesome on it.  Git and Svn are also awesome and much more stable.  It also has a plugin for chrome that will allow you to do on the fly changes with is pretty slick.  I haven't found anything I dislike yet.  Wish I would have changed a while ago.

Comment: k it seems same situation in netbeans 8

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--for HTML content-->
<%--  JSP comment  --%>
// inside scriptlet tag in JSP pages single line comment
/*
multi line comment inside scriptlet tag in JSP
*/
```

These are the right comment tags for JSP pages and HTML pages.